# Errno 2 "No such file or directory" encountered while trying to install pandas on macOS

Tags: python, pandas, macos-mojave

I am trying to install pandas using pip on Python 2.7.10. However, when I execute `pip install pandas` I get the following error:

```
Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError: [Errno 2] No 
such file or directory: '/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/idna- 
2.7.dist-info/METADATA'
```

Prior to this I have never used python or install any python packages on this system before. The python is pre-installed on the MacBook. Any advice on how to solve this?

Comment: What OS are you using?

Comment: @waqasgard macOS Mojave 10.14.1

Comment: Okay. I would suggest you get Python3 and then try the above. Pandas is dropping support for 2.7 from Jan 1st https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/install.html#plan-for-dropping-python-2-7

Answer (score 0):

From the looks, your missing the [idna](https://pypi.org/project/idna) package. A `pip install idna` will fix it.

**Update:** It seems like the `idna`package got corrupted. Try force reinstalling with `pip install idna --force-reinstall --ignore-installed`.

Comment: Seems like idna package is already installed but somehow it is missing some files.

pip install idna
Requirement already satisfied: idna in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages (2.7)
No metadata found in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages
Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/idna-2.7.dist-info/METADATA'

Comment: Seems like you got your files corrupted somehow. Updated my answer :)